# jQuery not triggering postback on button inside UpdatePanel

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a simple page with an UpdatePanel and two buttons:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Text="Search" OnClick="UpdateSearchResults" />

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Text="Search" OnClick="UpdateSearchResults" />
        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="PlaceHolder1"></asp:PlaceHolder>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" EventName="Click" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button2" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Clicking either button should run "UpdateSearchResults" on the server, which renders content into the placeholder.  Clicking either button manually works as espected - so far so good.

However, if I use jQuery to trigger the button click for Button2 programmatically, e.g.

```
$("Button2").click();
```

then the partial postback never happens, whereas it **does** if I do exactly the same thing to Button1.

I've tried:

- Substituting .click() with .trigger('click')
- Setting ChildrenAsTriggers to true
- Selecting the button using ClientID

all to no avail.  So what's going on here?  Why can I trigger the click event of one button but not the other?

Comment: Try `$("#Button2").click();`

Comment: you need the selector: `$('[id$="Button2"]')`  as ASP will prepend the container name to the control name, so @GuruprasadRao's suggestion won't work if your button is in another control on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is that you are missing the **`#`** sign in start of selector which specifies to use Id selector, and it is not guaranted that after control renders it will have the **Button2** as client side id on the browser unless you set **ClientIDMode** to **Static**, but i will not recomment to do that.

The better way is to use the [ClientID Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid(v=vs.110).aspx) of the Control which will cause compile time errors in future if you remove the button or change it's name, using magic strings will fail your client side code :

```
$('#<%= Button2.ClientID %>').click();
```

Comment: I can't believe I missed that!  Good tip on the ClientID property, too - I've always resisted using that; you just gave me a good reason to use it in the future.